# Parsing_exception: [range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

My DSL query is shown below. For some reason when I run it in Kibana CLI, it tells me:

[image]

```
GET elastic-search-app-log*/_search
{
  "size": 42,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "dateRanges": {
        "gte": "2021-05-20T10:15:00",
        "lte": "2021-05-18T14:58:00"
      }
    },
    "match": {
      "level": "Error"
    }
  }
}
```

I checked to see if maybe its the alignment of the braces but they look fine. Is there something causing this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine all the queries using [`bool/must`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause

```
{
  "size": 42,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "dateRanges": {
              "gte": "2021-05-20T10:15:00",
              "lte": "2021-05-18T14:58:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "level": "Error"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So whenever you have multiple queries you must include bool & match?

Comment: @Novice coder whenever you have multiple queries, you need to use bool query and you can combine those query using either `must/should/filter` clause acc to your use case

Comment: I understand now, thank you for the clarification and your help! Of course I can! :)